# MATLAB will not plot figure correctly

Tags: matlab

Why does MATLAB plot this figure as a straight horizontal line? `y1 = (1+(x/2))/(1-(x/2));`

What is wrong with the code?

The function is supposed to resemble e^x. Thank you. Code is here below.

```
x = linspace(0,3);
y1 = (1+(x/2))/(1-(x/2));

%Plot the lines.

figure
plot(x,y1)
```

Comment: Do you know the difference between `/` and `./`?

Comment: No. Can you kindly explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @nkjt pointed out:

Do you know the difference between `/` and `./`

If you want to divide pointwise, you have to use the `./`, otherwise you will get the result of the vector

**(1+(x/2))** divided by **(1+(x/2))**

What you want is:

`x = linspace(0,3); y1 = (1+(x/2))./(1-(x/2)); figure, plot(x,y1)`

Comment: thank @nkjt, give him an upvote as well .. also please mark the answer as answered so that the next person that has this problem can find the solution to it.